# Surface tension and surface energy

Tags: surface-tension

**Why spraying causes cooling**
if the work is not done by an external force then internal energy of liquid decreases subsequently temperature decreases.

**but in a a spray bottle we apply external mechanical force????**

Answer (score 0):

Spraying water into a fine mist causes a cooling effect *by evaporation of water from the droplet surfaces*. The lower the relative humidity of the surrounding air, the finer the mist, and the colder the water being sprayed, the greater the cooling effect.

This is called *evaporative cooling* and a full description can be found in any heating/ventilating/air-conditioning (HVAC) textbook under the heading of *airwash systems*.